# Deploy power-apps portal customization & configuration from Development to Production environment?

Tags: powerapp, dynamics-365, powerapps-portal, cds

We are developing one power-apps portal. We have custom Web Pages, Web Forms, Page Templates, Custom CSS, JavaScript & Image files in the portal. Also having some portal configuration like, Website settings, Entity permissions, Web Roles, Bindings.

I wanted to know about, **how to deploy all these portal files, customization & configuration from development environment to production environment?**

[This MSDN article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/admin/migrate-portal-configuration)  is related to migrating portal configurations but I want to know about entire portal deployment.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You've posted in SharePoint.stackexchange, but PowerApps Portals are a Dynamics365 capability.  This does not appear to be a SharePoint-related question -- should this be posted in Stackoverflow instead?

Comment: Hey @SPDeveloper did you find the way to do it?